# Why buy a first class ticket on Southern trains?

Tags: uk, trains, luxury

I have been traveling regularly to the south and I would love to know the benefits of upgrading to first class because to me it seems like there is [none](https://www.southernrailway.com/tickets/ticket-types-explained/first-class)

Comment: Even if there is no difference in services or facilities, paying more will generally lead to emptier and quieter spaces. At least that’s how it seems to work in the Netherlands.

Comment: Is standard class four across or five across on the trains you use?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I can’t remember but it’s the trains that go to Hastings, Ore, Hayward Heath (where trains divide) and Lewis.

Comment: @Calchas “improved probability” that’s crazy? It’s not even “ a guaranteed seat”

Comment: It might be for non-obvious commercial reasons. For example, if you buy a first class ticket from Glasgow to Brighton, you'd travel on Virgin West Coast to London and then Southern to Brighton. Perhaps by notionally offering first class, Southern get a larger proportion of first class ticket sales, even though those sales might be made on the basis of the first class service on Virgin rather than on Southern. I couldn't work out how revenue is split for first class fares, so this is speculation.

Comment: @Ulkoma I turned my comment into an answer. But, no, I found to my surprise that the seat is not guaranteed in law, however, most TOCs will quietly offer you a refund back to standard class if you complain about the lack of a seat.

Comment: On many commuter lines during busy hours trains don't have a 1st class technically.Southern is also one of them.Unless you intend to get into an argument with a traveller, hold thy peace.And it would be foolish to upgrade if you cannot be guaranteed a seat. And not on Southern atleast. They are the same seats as the others, with just a First class logo.

Comment: @DumbCoder the logo is on a nice piece of cloth that goes under your head. My guess it’s make of silk.

Comment: So you don't have to travel with the oiks in standard, obviously.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's the improved probability of a seat during rush hour and (in my opinion) the likelihood of quieter, or indeed absent, companions outside of rush hour. That's pretty much it; there's no difference in the hard product, and there's no soft product to speak of.

This is now counterbalanced by the very small first class section, which means if you have a random distribution of first class passengers, it doesn't take many people to fill it up even on a quiet service, and sometimes you may as well move to an empty part of the standard coach.

For many of us, the prospect of a quiet place to sit to read or work is well worth a few extra pounds on a journey of an hour or more. Yet, even I, who value this enough to travel almost never in standard class on a long journey, think Southern's first class is a bit of a joke, and I have stopped buying first on Southern services. (I am similarly displeased about the new carriages South Western Rail have introduced, with the 2-2 non-reclining first seats. I think it is a big downgrade.)

As I remember the operator would prefer to remove the first class section altogether but is forbidden by its franchising agreement.

Comment: Some people are entitled to travel first class by their employer when traveling for business (eg, senior civil servants). So if it's offered, they might pay for it even if it has almost zero benefit. If Southern don't offer it then they're leaving money on the table.

Comment: @MJeffryes That's true but with one class the benefits are reduced need for on-board ticket inspection (replace staff with automated barriers) and increased capacity for standard class ticket holders. For Southern, I suspect the money is in season tickets, less so one-off expensed journeys. Many commuter London services on other operators now run standard class only. But this is just my speculation.

Comment: On the Cambridge-London services I've not seen a ticket inspector in years but they still have first class. I suppose they don't care to enforce it when the benefits are so minimal.

Comment: It is similar on most local and regional services in Germany with 1st class compartments. The seats are the same and the only advantage is that you are more likely to find a free seat during rush hours or having more room otherwise.

Comment: On Thameslink trains there’s a (tiny() first class section at both ends. The section at the rear of the train is always declassified - I always travel first class without needing to pay for for it on those journeys.

Comment: Fairly certain most trains have a higher proportion of people with no ticket at all than a first class ticket seated in the first class section these days.

Comment: @MJeffryes I've seen ticket inspectors on the same route, but I normally do it at weekends. On GWR's new IETs (London-Cardiff/Swansea) most trains have on-board ticket checks as well as barriers at most/all of their stops.  It would be trivial to connect from a train boarded at a station without barriers.

Comment: I was half expecting any answer to have a reference to bus replacement services, but maybe Southern have improved and actually have trains now.

Comment: I m on the train at the moment. It’s packed and first class has been declassified. A white collar posh guy is making a scene because he has a first class ticket yet there is no empty seat for him to occupy.... nice..

Answer (score 0):

[This video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=l4ADNYRJlKM) did a review of first class and here are the advantages:

- Reading lights
- Power sockets
- Increased privacy
- More space
- More luxurious experience
- Better presentation

But to be honest, on shorter journeys and even on longer ones it isn’t really worth it in my opinion.

Comment: I kind of disagree with your answer. I have been travelling frequently and it’s the same seats, no extra space no power sockets and even no guaranteed seat. However I’ll measure the seats next week.

Comment: Power sockets are becoming much common in Standard on other operators, as carriages are replaced or refitted; the seats are certainly bigger and softer in First, on most configurations

Comment: @ChrisH I travel regularly on SouthWestern - and there are power sockets in standard class now - on all trains that I've been on in the past couple of months.

Comment: @AleksG I am not sure which trains you travel one but no power sockets on all the ones running on the route I travel via.

Comment: @Ulkoma It may be a matter of old/new trains.  I usually travel Woking to/from London on "fast" trains.

Comment: Trains which have power sockets like these in 1st class also have them in standard, similarly if they aren't in standard, they probably don't have them in 1st either.